# byte collection based similar with ByteBuffer from java

Tags: c#, java, bytebuffer

I need a C# implementation of something similar with ByteBuffer from Java. Methods of interest
- .remaining() - returns the number of elements between the current position and the limit.
- .array() 
- .clear()
- .put(byte[], int, int)

I started something with `MemoryStream`.. but no `clear()`, and a lot of improvisation
Also, i found a c# implementation on Koders: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid2F8CB1B540E646746D3ADCB2B0AC867A0A8DCB06.aspx?s=socket#L2.. which I will use.. but maybe you guys know something better

Comment: `put->Write`, `clear->Position=0`, `array()->ToArray()`  etc. I can't see what you can't do with MemoryStream.

Comment: @L.B, setting `Position` to 0 is not equivalent to `clear`... but `SetLength(0)` would be

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`MemoryStream` can do everything you want:

- `.array()` => `.ToArray()`
- `.clear()` => `.SetLength(0)`
- `.put(byte[], int, int)` => `.Write(byte[], int, int)`
- `.remaining()` => `.Length - .Position`

If you want, you can create extension methods for `Clear` and `Remaining`:

```
public static class MemoryStreamExtensions
{
    public static void Clear(this MemoryStream stream)
    {
        stream.SetLength(0);
    }

    public static int Remaining(this MemoryStream stream)
    {
        return stream.Length - stream.Position;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `ByteBuffer.allocate(int)` ?

Comment: @Paul, `new MemoryStream(int)`

Answer (score 3):

MemoryStream should have everything you are looking for. Combined with BinaryWriter to write different data types.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.SetLength(100);

long remaining = ms.Length - ms.Position; //remaining()

byte[] array = ms.ToArray(); //array()

ms.SetLength(0); //clear()

ms.Write(buffer, index, count); //put(byte[], int, int)
```

Answer (score -4):

Are you looking for a `Queue<T>`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

For some of the methods that Queue doesn't support, it might be easy enough to write a custom class that wraps a Queue.

Comment: Queue only allows adding and removing single elements.